# How to describe custom data type that Entity Framework was able to properly serialize/deserialize?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

There is a model of this type:

```
public class Pub
{
   [Key]
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public StringList Items { get; set; } // <--
}
```

Class StringList contains the property Value, which performs the serialization/deserialization to/from string.

```
   public class StringList
   {
      ...
      public string Value
      {
         get { return this.ToString(); }
         set { this.FillFromString(value); }
      }
   }
```

How to explain the EF that when filling the model from the database you need to set the value in model.Items.Value, and when reading from the model to the database to retrieve the value from the model.Items.Value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get Entity Framework to do any of that. It's not designed to manipulate data, only to retrieve it. However, you can solve the issue in a roundabout way. Knowing that Entity Framework will just fill properties from database data, you can do something like:

```
public string ItemsString { get; set; }

[NotMapped]
public string Items
{
    get { return FillFromString(ItemsString); }
    set { ItemsString = value.ToString(); }
}
```

In other words, `ItemsString` is what gets persisted and then your `Items` property converts this to/from whatever structure you need, dynamically. You just utilize `Items` as necessary in your application and it's set it and forget it.